# Ubuntu 20.04, HP ProBook 445 G7 4700U black screen after boot

Tags: hp, amd-graphics, amdgpu, amd-ryzen

I've already seen this topic but not sure it makes sense to post an 'answer' with a question.

I have an HP ProBook 445 G7 Laptop with the 4700U and can't for the life of me isolate how to get the gpu to come online consistently. On an Ubuntu 20 system with an almost bleeding edge 5.8 kernel, if I set 'nomodeset=0', the gpu comes up and works the first time maybe and up correct resolution, screen brightness adjustment works (another complaint I've heard), cool. Next time it boots, screen goes black and I got nothing. I've tried permutations on setting text and console mode in grub. Doesn't work. I know it's booted since I can type in the password (blind) and prove that I'm in X. I can boot myself into 4:3 1024x768 in a safe mode but yeah, yuck. Should I expect that if I wait long enough HP, AMD or someone will fix this or does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: GPUs usually do not load. Not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 1):

This is why Ubuntu makes it hard to upgrade to the latest kernel, to prevent problems like this from happening. I'd recommend trying an older kernel if you haven't deleted the original kernel yet; when you boot up your computer, press the ESC key *right before* the computer starts booting into Ubuntu. Then use the UP/DOWN arrow keys and the Enter key to navigate the Grub boot menu. Select "Advanced options for Ubuntu" and then select the kernel that the graphics worked with before. Remove the newer kernel, and move on.

This *might* not work, depending on what's causing the issue, but it's worth a try anyways.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry yeah I should have mentioned why I updated to the latest kernel. I had the same issues with the older kernel except it didn't work even once. Either vesa safemode or black screen. Research suggested the 5.8 kernel and I actually had at least a few times it booted to the correct gpu settings and worked fine, then I'd reboot and get the black screen. So I sense that it's very close to working but just isn't consistent.